# Force ServiceStack to include a null field in JSON output?

Tags: servicestack

This is the object definition:

```
Public Class ApplicationError
    Public Property Id As Integer
    Public Property Application As Application ' object defined elsewhere
    Public Property Task As String
    Public Property Description As String
    Public Property ErrorTimestamp As DateTime
    Public Property RestartTimestamp As DateTime? ' <-- nullable
    Public Property ApplicationStopped As Boolean
End Class
```

The response message definition contains a property `Result() As ApplicationError`. The JSON produced looks like this:

```
{
    "Result": [
        {
            "Id": 4,
            "Application": {
                "ID": 4,
                "Name": "An Application",
                ...
            },
            "Task": "Fake Error",
            "Description": "Data to validate monitoring app.",
            "ErrorTimestamp": "2015-01-23T12:22:01.5830000",
            "ApplicationStopped": false
        }
    ]
}
```

Notice that there is no `RestartTimestamp` property in that `Result` object. This data is going to a Knockout application. Knockout is going to throw an error because the `RestartTimestamp` property is missing. I need a `RestartTimestamp: null` property. Yes, I could add code in my client application to do this. I really don't want to do that; the client application is rather orderly and I'd like to keep it that way.

How can I make ServiceStack create the `RestartTimestamp: null` property that I need?

Answer (score 3):

You can configure to emit `null` properties with:

```
JsConfig.IncludeNullValues = true;
```