# What is the industry standard in serializing null attributes in REST based services?

Tags: json, xml, rest, standards

Recently there was discussion with my colleague about proper industry standards, in dealing with XML/JSON format resonses, having elements with null values. My view is to ignore/not including the elements in XML and JSON responses, if a particular element has null values. My belief is it would reduce the payload size and lesser bandwidth in transmission.

Where as my colleagues argument is to include all the attributes/elements defined in JSON/XML, whether there is value or not.

So ideally, it is like

```
<name>John Doe</name>
 vs
<name>John Doe</name>
<DOB/>
```

Similarly

```
{
  "name":"John Doe"
}
vs
{
   "name":"John Doe",
   "DOB":null
}
```

What is the correct approach and why ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is probably no right or wrong approach, it depends on the requirements of the application. That's why [Newtonsoft](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_NullValueHandling.htm) or [ServiceStack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28118935/force-servicestack-to-include-a-null-field-in-json-output) allow you to configure whether or not you wan't to include null values.

Answer (score 0):

```
<name>John Doe</name>
 vs
<name>John Doe</name>
<DOB/>
```

Careful! Those two representations aren't quite equivalent.  `<DOB/>` denotes an [empty element](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-starttags); it is equivalent to `<DOB></DOB>`.  Empty and null aren't generically interchangeable - this is why we have both `204 No Content` and `404 Not Found`, both `-s` and `-e`.

> What is the correct approach and why ?

I believe you want to be thinking about this question within the larger context of *messaging*.  In an ideal world, we would have a schema that describes each of the fields in our message -- what the semantics of the fields are, the allowed range of values, which fields are required, and which are optional, and the default semantics when optional fields are absent.

In a distributed system, where clients and servers deploy at a different cadence, it is common to [extend](https://www.xml.com/pub/a/2004/10/27/extend.html) a schema with additional semantics over the lifetime of the contract.  But if the clients and servers are independently deployed, you will have situations where the client and server understand different versions of the same schema.  So we need to be careful about forward and backwards compatibility, and the constraints on our changes necessary to keep everything working.

(Of course, we'll eventually want to make an incompatible change.  So we'll need to introduce a new message schema, and that in turn implies that we need to be thinking about message [life cycles](http://hintjens.com/blog:85)).

What this implies is that, in general, we need to be prepared for any optional field to be missing -- because the message may have been produced by a process that only knows about schema versions prior to the introduction of the new field.

So for the optional case, should a producer that's aware of an optional field always include it in the message?  I don't know of any published arguments in favor of that, beyond the general advice that explicit improves upon implicit.